# Starting MS SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, windows, sql-server-2014-express

I just downloaded and installed [MS SQL Server 2014 Express](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/products/sql-server-editions/sql-server-express.aspx) on my Win 8.1 machine.
Unfortunately I can't figure out, how to run it.
I just need a simple client, where I can run my SQL statements and do some processing with windows-related programming languages.

This is how my folder structure looks like:

[image: screenshot]

I've already read "[Start, Stop, Pause, Resume, Restart the Database Engine, SQL Server Agent, or SQL Server Browser Service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh403394.aspx)", but it wasn't what I'm looking for.

Comment: You need `SQL Server Management Studio` to run queries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [SQL Server Management Studio Express](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174173.aspx).

You can [download it here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/dn434042.aspx).

Comment: Is it already bundled with SQL Server? If so, do I have to uninstall SQL Server, before installing Management Studio?

Comment: [SQL Server Management Studio Express (SQLManagementStudio)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/dn434042.aspx) - "Use this if you already have the database and only need the management tools."

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed SQL Server, but cannot find the SSMS, look in your root folder for the installation, it will be along the lines of .... Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\Ssms.exe

Or just search for Ssms.exe to locate the exe file, and create a shortcut on your Start Menu.